# Hibernate Search: MassIndexer and missing CDI-Scopes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cdi, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate search and run a MassIndexer like this:

```
FullTextEntityManager ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
ftem.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

The problems in respect to missing cdi-scopes in the MassIndexer-threads occur at two places:

javax.persistence.PostLoad

```
@PostLoad
void onPostLoad(Object o) {
   // cdi-scope aware code
}
```

org.hibernate.search.bridge.FieldBridge

```
class MyFieldBridge implements FieldBridge {
   public void set(...) {
      // cdi-scope aware code
   }
}
```

Is it possible to enrich the MassIndexer threads with a defined CDI-scope (e.g. via Apache Deltaspike)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly, but I believe you use CDI beans in your field bridge, and those CDI beans have a scope that is neither "application" nor "singleton"?

As far as I can tell, there is no way to customize how threads are started by the mass indexer, or to wrap custom code around mass indexer executions, so I don't think there's an obvious way to do what you want.

If you have a precise idea of what would be needed from an API point of view, you can open a ticket on [our JIRA instance](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH/) describing it in details. We also warmly welcome patches if you're feeling up to some coding ;)

Regarding the non-obvious solutions:

- Hibernate Search 5.9+ provides a JSR-352 (Batch for Java applications) integration, which allows you to run a mass indexing JSR-352 job. The integration works with JBeret in particular, which runs inside Weld, and executes the mass indexing code in custom CDI scopes. You might be able to customize this to do what you want.
- There might be some transaction scope in your CDI implementation, that is automatically activated when a transaction is opened by Hibernate ORM. If it's the case (I really don't know if it is), you might be able to automatically activate the scope you need whenever a transaction scope is activated and your scope isn't active yet. Really a shot in the dark, but who knows...

Also, you may want to ask yourself why you need a non-application, non-singleton scope in a field bridge, considering field bridges are supposed to act the same regardless of who requested their execution: you probably wouldn't want an entity to be indexed differently each time a different users changes it... You might have your reasons, but you'd better check these are really good ones.